# Google Maps not working trying for 3 days

Tags: google-maps-api-2

I have done everything according to this page:-https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start
But i only see a blank grey page with Google logo and +/- sign. Some people say my API key is wrong but i have generated my API key a 100 times but still no luck. My code is the same as provided on Google developer page. I have given the link above. I am done trying everything now please someone help me.

This is my java code:-

```
package com.example.gps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

This is my xml layout code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

This is my manifest code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyA0aKSCV1vZXmJN4Xht440rDWu8NWqrgD0" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Also it is working on my emlator but not my device

Comment: Can you, for sanity and completeness sake, put a copy of your code in the question?

Comment: yep now i added the codes......thx for the reply though

Comment: anyone has the solution??????? please reply asap

Comment: The [google-maps-api-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-2) is the deprecated Google Maps Javascript API v2.  Perhaps you should tag this android?

Comment: i cant understand what you are trying to say

Comment: Your question is tagged wrong. The topic of the tag you applied is the deprecated Google Maps Javascript API v2, which is not what you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution people.
When you export your apk make sure you export it with debug.keystore.
i.e., The same SHA1 signature which you registered with Google API console.